# Fixed or random effect for time in GLMM

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, glmm

I'm using GLMMTMB to build a model that predicts the state of fish stocks based on management attributes. The model contains an AR1 term for each stock and regional and taxon level random effects to control for regional and taxon level variation. I keep going back and forth on if I should include year dummies as a fixed or random effect. I'm not interested in predicting the effects for each different year and it's more a nuisance variable than a variable of interest. We have 28 years so that is also ok. This seems to me to satisfy some reasons to include it as a grouping variable (random effect).

However, there is a clear trend with time; the status of the stocks is getting better in more recent years (which is in essence collinear with the implementation of more sophisticated management regimes). Does this violate some assumption so that it can no longer be modeled as a random effect? I've read that there is a requirement for random effects to be "exchangeable", but I don't know what this means and I can't find a good source for this. If anyone has a good reference for that, this would be immensely appreciated.

Many thanks for any guidance anyone can give!